# button click after input radio checked

Tags: javascript, html

Clicking this button but, I cannot input radio checked.

```
<button class="button" style="width:100px;">
  <input class="radio" type="radio" name="choose" value="1"> value 1
</button><br><br>
<button class="button" style="width:100px;">
  <input class="radio" type="radio" name="choose" value="2"> value 2
</button><br><br>
<button class="button" style="width:100px;">
  <input class="radio" type="radio" name="choose" value="3"> value 3
</button><br><br>
<button class="button" style="width:100px;">
  <input class="radio" type="radio" name="choose" value="4"> value 4
</button>
```

js:

```
$(".button").click(function (){
$('input[name=choose]').attr('checked', true);
}
```

how can I do it?

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fpwh14e3/)

Comment: You're missing `)` at the end of the `click()` function.

Comment: Didn't you see the error message in the JavaScript console?

Comment: Which button do you want to check? You can only check one button at a time in a radio group, so you need to be more specific in your selector.

Comment: and you don't include jquery in your jsfiddle example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of finding by the global selector, you need to use the button you clicked as the context by which you search in.  This way you only check the nested input and do not try to check all of them, thus checking most likely only the last one.

```js
$('.button').on('click', e => {
  $('input', e.target).prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button" style="width:100px;">
  <input class="radio" type="radio" name="choose" value="1"> value 1
</button><br><br>
<button class="button" style="width:100px;">
  <input class="radio" type="radio" name="choose" value="2"> value 2
</button><br><br>
<button class="button" style="width:100px;">
  <input class="radio" type="radio" name="choose" value="3"> value 3
</button><br><br>
<button class="button" style="width:100px;">
  <input class="radio" type="radio" name="choose" value="4"> value 4
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use prop instead.

```
$(".button").click(function (e){
$('input', e.target).prop('checked', true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".button").click(function (){
   $(this).find('input.radio').attr('checked', true)
})
```

Try updating it like this?

Please see jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gto9ck47/1/

Comment: Please use Stack Snippets instead of jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try Pure javascript without embeding 80kb code to your website

<button class="button" style="width:100px;">
  <input class="radio" type="radio" name="choose" value="1"> value 1
</button><br><br>
<button class="button" style="width:100px;">
  <input class="radio" type="radio" name="choose" value="2"> value 2
</button><br><br>
<button class="button" style="width:100px;">
  <input class="radio" type="radio" name="choose" value="3"> value 3
</button><br><br>
<button class="button" style="width:100px;">
  <input class="radio" type="radio" name="choose" value="4"> value 4
</button>


<script>

    let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button');

    buttons.forEach(button =>{
        button.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
            button.children[0].checked = true;
        });
    })

</script>
```